# VSTO outlook plugin development

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

I need to show popup on meeting end in Outlook.
Can anyone tell the any event in "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook" on which i can display the popup.?
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such event. But you can create a list of times when a popup needs to be shown and use your own timer (use the one from the Forms namespace - it fires on the main thread) to check if a popup needs to be shown.